# mutliprocessing TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cartopy

I try to use multiprocessing to plot locations into a map, since there can be many locations which can take some time and I often have to tweak little thinks and then try again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tbade\Documents\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\map.py", line 39, in <module>
    pool.starmap(multiprocessing_func, zip(pop_lon, pop_lat))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

That is the error message I get for

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

df = pd.read_csv('passport.csv')

pop_lat = df['latitude'].tolist()[:-2]
pop_lon = df['longitude'].tolist()[:-2]

central_lat, central_lon = np.median(pop_lat), np.median(pop_lon)
extent = [central_lon - 3, central_lon + 3.4, central_lat - 2.2, central_lat + 2]
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_lon, central_lat))
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS)
plt.show()

def multiprocessing_func(lon, lat):
    for x, y in zip(lon, lat):
        ax.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(multiprocessing_func, zip(pop_lon, pop_lat))
```

also I get multiple figures

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both `pop_lat` and `pop_lon` appear to be lists of floats.  That means that the arguments to multiprocessing_func are two floats, not two lists of floats.  Hence your error.    It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with your multiprocessing.

Comment: This questin would be better with a MRE (we don't have your passport.csv).  It would also likely make it clearer to you what's going on

Comment: I should also add, I have no idea what happens when you make multiple calls to `plot` in different threads.  I don't know if that's supported, and if you're going to get multiple plots or one plot.  I repeat, what part of this are you trying to parallelize.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution because it's not clear what exactly you're trying to parallelize, as @FrankYellin mentions in the comments. This is just an explanation of what's wrong, which is too much for a comment.

The way you've implemented `multiprocessing_func`, it is implicitly expecting two iterables, `lat` and `lon`, because you are trying to `zip` them, and you can only `zip` iterables.

But what you're doing with your `starmap` call is pairing floats into tuples, and then unpacking those floats (the "star" in `starmap`) as arguments to `multiprocessing_func`. Here's a demonstration of how the `starmap` is working since you didn't provide sample data:

```py
In [1]: from itertools import starmap

In [2]: def adder(a, b):
   ...:     print(a, b)
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:

In [3]: list(starmap(adder, zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 1, 6, 2])))
1 5
2 2
3 1
4 6
5 2
Out[3]: [6, 4, 4, 10, 7]
```